# Dependency conflict in google-cloud-speech

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-speech

I'm experimenting with Google cloud speech to text service. It works OK, but I can't update the version of the google-cloud-speech. If I put more recent version instead of `0.41.0-alpha` it throws this error as soon as I try to launch it:

```
16681-16681/com.example.voice_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.voice_test, PID: 16681
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class 
Lio/grpc/internal/AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder; or its super classes (declaration of 
'io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder' appears in /data/app/com.example.voice_test- 
dOPemX43m_vBjq_Tc8tk7w==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
```

How to fix this error?

Gradle dependecies for speech recognition:

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.41.0-alpha'
```

Creating the speech client:

```
private val mSpeechClient by lazy {
    applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credential).use {
        SpeechClient.create(
            SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider { GoogleCredentials.fromStream(it) }
                .build())
    }
}
```

OnCreate function. The speech recorder itself is using AudioRecord class, nothing special there.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.last_recognize_result)
    mSpeakButton = findViewById(R.id.button)

    // get permissions
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION)

    val config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
        .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
        .setLanguageCode(LANGCODE)
        .build()

    val audioRecorder = AudioRecorder()
    val clicker: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        val byteArrayAudio: ByteString = audioRecorder.record(5000)

        val audio: RecognitionAudio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
            .setContent(byteArrayAudio).build()

        val resultsList = mSpeechClient.recognize(config, audio).resultsList

        for (result in resultsList) {
            val resultText = result.alternativesList[0].transcript
            mTextView.setText(resultText)
            Log.d(TAG, "-- Transcription: %s".format(resultText))
        }

    }
    mSpeakButton.setOnClickListener(clicker)
}
```

Comment: Can you check your dependency tree and see if there is a version conflict of io.grpc library?

Comment: @user675693 I ran the "dependencies" command, it executed without errors. Only if running without --scan it shows "No configurations". Don't know what this means. Sorry, I'm quite lame with gradle :(

Comment: @user675693 I ran the command properly, it doesn't seem to show any conflicts.

Comment: Maybe I need to put up more information? I'm still struggling with this issue - need help.

Comment: What's the output of the command
"gradle dependencies --configuration=runtimeClasspath | grep io.grpc"
? All the grpc versions should be 1.10.0, otherwise NoSuchMethodError can happen.

Comment: @user675693 it fails with: Configuration with name 'runtimeClasspath' not found.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you are using android. Then you should run the gradle command in the app directory with "gradle dependencies --configuration=releaseRuntimeClasspath | grep io.grpc"

Answer (score 0):

i face the same problem and then I update the version - implementation `io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.10.0` update this version to implementation `io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.54.1` and google resolved this issue.